# Refactoring decision tree

Tags: javascript

Currently I have

```
var l1 = [...];
var l2 = [...]; 
if (l1.length > l2.length){
    var i = l2.indexOf(l1[0]);
    if (i !== -1){
        action_a(i);
    }else{
        action_c();
    }
} else if (l1.length < l2.length){
    var i = l1.indexOf(l2[0]);
    if (i !== -1){
        action_b(i);
    }else{
        action_c();
    }
} else {
    action_c();
}
```

Which I have could refactor into the following

```
function foo() {
    var l1 = [...];
    var l2 = [...];
    var i = -1;
    if (l1.length > l2.length){
        i = l2.indexOf(l1[0]);
    } else if (l1.length < l2.length){
        i = l1.indexOf(l2[0]);
    }
    if (i === -1 || l1.length == l2.length) {
        action_c();
        return;
    }
    if (l1.length > l2.length){
        action_a(i);
    } else if (l1.length < l2.length){
        action_b(i);
    }
}
```

It's a bit better, but I'm checking for the length of the two array twice.  It's also still not as readable as I would like it to be.

Can you review the above code and offer recommendations on how to do this better?

Comment: Is there a typo on the 4th line of the original code?  Should `l[0]` be `l1[0]`?  The same typo seems to be in the refactored code as well.

Comment: Yea that is a typo, I will fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After re-reading the question I realized my answer was the same as your original code. Which frankly I don't see a problem with (the upper one, the later one is worse).

It has a clear structure which says "Okay, I'm treating three cases: less, equals and greater and doing different things in each case.

If you want to get rid of the duplication of calls to `action_c` you can do like so:

```
var l1 = [...];
var l2 = [...]; 
if (l1.length > l2.length){
    var i = l2.indexOf(l1[0]);
    if (i !== -1){
        action_a(i);
        return;
    }
} else if (l1.length < l2.length){
    var i = l1.indexOf(l2[0]);
    if (i !== -1){
        action_b(i);
        return;
    }
} 
action_c();
```

But I would argue it's less readable as it's not immediately obvious when `action_c` is called as it is in the original. But in this case it's splitting hairs IMHO.

edit: corrected variable name

Comment: The problem with the first fragment is that I have action_c() scattered all over the tree, which might be fine, but it doesn't feel right

Comment: Edited for how to get rid of `action_c` being everywhere. Although I don't think it's a problem that it is, it makes it easier to analyse.

Comment: Fair enough, I think I will just stick to the original

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, but as you can see from the lack of up-votes on my answer you might want to wait a bit and see if some one else has some other tips.

Comment: Good call, I guess I will come back later

Comment: @EmilyL you will need to wrap the code in a function to use return, other than that looks great.

Comment: That's left as an exercise for the reader. I just showed the idea ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
var l1 = [...];
var l2 = [...]; 
if (l1.length > l2.length){
    actOnDuplicateOfFirstElementIfPresent(l1, l2, action_a);
} else if (l1.length < l2.length){
    actOnDuplicateOfFirstElementIfPresent(l2, l1, action_b);
} else {
    action_c();
}

function actOnDuplicateOfFirstElementIfPresent(la, lb, action) {
    var i = lb.indexOf(la[0]);
    if (i !== -1){
        action(i);
    }else{
        action_c();
    }
}
```

This Extract Method refactoring eliminates the duplication found in the first two branches.  Eliminating duplication is both an excellent motivation, and an excellent technique, for refactoring.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but would you please explain the changes that you made and why you made them?

Comment: I saw duplication in the first two branches, so I extracted the method.  Eliminating duplication is one of the best techniques and motivations for refactoring.

Comment: Factoring into more functions is always an option. But in this particular case I feel that the call to foo hides the notion that `action_c()` acts as a kind of "fallback" if the other conditions fail. But then again it all depends on the semantics of the three functions and their relations.

Comment: I think that's only a problem because of the name "foo".  Not knowing anything else about this code it was impossible to come up with a meaningful name.

Comment: @CarlManaster, I was meaning to add definition to your code inside your answer post, Code only answers are frowned upon in much of the StackExchange Network.

Comment: Thanks, @Malachi; updated per your suggestion; I didn't understand your original comment.

Comment: True, the name `foo` didn't help, but I think there is a fine line when you factor too much into functions that you can't follow the algorithm for all the function jumps if you see what I mean?

Comment: Great by the book refactoring technique! I will remember this for the future

Comment: @EmilyL. I've updated the name of the extracted method; maybe it helps.

Comment: +1 for this refactoring.  The structure of the original code suggests that `action_a` and `action_b` may be closely related.  If we had seen the bodies of those functions, it might be easier to decide if this refactoring is "right" for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that some of the variables didn't add up  `l` and `l1` I assumed that `l` is supposed to be `l1` in the code that I wrote.

I moved the actions into their respective places because I couldn't see a reason that you couldn't merge them before checking for the lengths being equal or `i` being unassigned.

```
function foo() {
    var l1 = [...];
    var l2 = [...];
    var i = -1;

    if (l1.length > l2.length){
        i = l2.indexOf(l1[0]);
        action_a(i);
    } else if (l1.length < l2.length){
        i = l1.indexOf(l2[0]);
         action_b(i);
    } else if (i === -1 || l1.length == l2.length) {
        action_c();
    }
}
```

From here I can see that the `i` variable is something that you don't really need, so I go a step further

```
function foo() {
    var l1 = [...];
    var l2 = [...];

    if (l1.length > l2.length){
        action_a(l2.indexOf(l1[0]));
    } else if (l1.length < l2.length){
         action_b(l1.indexOf(l2[0]));
    } else if (l1.length == l2.length) {
        action_c();
    }
}
```

I think this is what you want.

---

upon further reading it appears that you want an else statement to perform `action_c();` if one is not greater than the other or something else happens, so you could perform one less check at the end

```
function foo() {
    var l1 = [...];
    var l2 = [...];

    if (l1.length > l2.length){
        action_a(l2.indexOf(l1[0]));
    } else if (l1.length < l2.length){
         action_b(l1.indexOf(l2[0]));
    } else {
        action_c();
    }
}
```

---

I realize that I left out a check for either Array being empty,  so I remedy this like:

```
function foo() {
    var l1 = [...];
    var l2 = [...];


    if (l1.length > l2.length  && l2.length > 0){
        action_a(l2.indexOf(l1[0]));
    } else if (l1.length < l2.length && l1.length > 0){
         action_b(l1.indexOf(l2[0]));
    } else {
        action_c();
    }
}
```

---

I left out a check for if the match is not found
so I have added a couple of ternaries

```
function foo() {
    var l1 = [...];
    var l2 = [...];


    if (l1.length > l2.length  && l2.length > 0){
        l2.indexOf(l1[0]) ? action_a(l2.indexOf(l1[0])) : action_c();
    } else if (l1.length < l2.length && l1.length > 0){
         l1.indexOf(l2[0]) ? action_b(l1.indexOf(l2[0])) : action_c();
    } else {
        action_c();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the case where the `indexOf` operator doesn't find the element in the list and returns `-1` which I assume is an invalid argument to `action_a` and `action_b`. So your code is not functionally equivalent.

Comment: @EmilyL. now it does, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Looking at the last edit, its essentially the original code, with the detriment of using indexOf twice. Also, if both arrays are empty, it will fall through to the else block anyways, adding an if is just more checks. (both arrays are length of 5, it first check if both are empty then check twice to find their length are equal)

Comment: @XrXrXr if either is empty then it will stop at the first or second check, if they aren't empty there is a possible match, so we check for that. still thinking about the `indexOf` function though...  this code is much cleaner and clearer though

Comment: indexOf would return -1 anyways when either array is empty, so existing early doesn't really save much, since it adds overhead when both are not. There is also the problem of indexOf returning 0, which is false-ish to the ternary, resulting in a faulty call to action_c()

Comment: @XrXrXr so you are saying that there doesn't need to be a check for empty arrays?

Comment: yes, all the cases cover empty array already.